# How to make bookmarklet to calculate two numbers?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I would like to make a bookmarklet that pop up and takes a number then multiply it by 3.9.

Thank you so much.

Comment: this isn't icanhazcode.com - you need to try, fail and then ask

Comment: Do your own homework buddy

Answer (score 0):

Create a new bookmark with the URL set to:

`javascript:number = prompt("Please enter a number: "); alert("The product of your number and 3.9 is: " + number * 3.9);`